# add an attribute to multiple functions

Tags: python

I have multiple functions, I want to add the same attribute to them, but do not want to specify it in each of them, how do I achieve this?

```
def func(a, b):
  c = a%b
  return a + b + c

def func2(a, b):
  c = a%b
  retrun a - b + c

def func3(a, b):
  c = a%b
  retrun a * b + c
```

is ther an alternative to add `c = a%b` to each of them.

Comment: Write `def y(self, b): return self.x(b)` instead?

Comment: the methods y and z do a lot more, they have different implementations. need to use partial, because am using `self.x(b, ...)` multiple times, want to avoid it.

Comment: @apostofes, it still not clear why you are using `partial()` instead of simple method call

Comment: Simplified examples are good, but this is a bit too simple. We need to know more about what you're trying to accomplish and what your constraints or desires are.

Comment: We can't just blindly guess what are the "bunch of things" you need to do with `a`, so we cannot come up with an alternative idea. 99% of the time, when you have a function object, you call it and do something with the returned value.

Comment: i have edited it, could the person who closed it check if it could be reopened

Comment: Make `a%b` another function that you call…?! `return a + b + f(a, b)`. That's what you usually do if you want to reuse code. If `c` isn't injected as a parameter, then you also can't use a decorator or something that would do this "externally". But maybe you could rewrite this using decorators; again, this depends on your goals and constraints, which your simple toy example doesn't convey.